# Script not exiting on error bash ios

Tags: ios, bash, error-handling

So I am having to do my own error handling and am running into issues, the code below is causing the issue.

```
sbalert -t "Checking" -m "Checking for updates please wait" -d "" & 
alert_id="$!" 
ping -c 1 repod00r.com || kill $alert_id && sbalert -t "Connection error" -m "Unable to connect to the update server." && exit
```

whenever the ping **succeeds or fails** I get the error handler thrown and once I close the `sbalert` the `sbalert -t "Checking" -m "Checking for updates please wait" -d ""` reappears on screen when it should have been killed.

I have already tried re-ordering the three parts of the error handling around to try and fix this. But to no avail...

I am a bit of a noob, so sorry if the answer is punching me in the face...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, the connectors `||` and `&&` are simply executed left to right. `||` does not have higher precedence.

Try this to see how it works:

```
true || echo 1 && echo 2
false || echo 1 && echo 2
false || false && echo 1 && echo 2
```

So when you do: (simplified)

```
ping || kill $alert_id && sbalert && exit
```

The `kill` only executes if the `ping` fails, but the `sbalert` executes if either the `ping` or the `kill` succeed, and `exit` executes if the `sbalert` executed and succeeded.

So if the `ping` succeeds, the second `sbalert` will execute, but the original `sbalert` will not be killed, which seems to be what you are experiencing.

Your code would be easier to read and write with `if` statements:

```
sbalert -t "Checking" -m "Checking for updates please wait" -d "" &
alert_id=$!
if ! ping -c 1 repod00r.com; then
    kill $alert_id
    sbalert  -t "Connection error" -m "Unable to connect to the update server."
    exit
fi
```

Comment: I have yet to test (booting my pc) this but it looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: Should `if ping -c 1 repod00r.com [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then` work? as its for anything that doesn't exit zero.

Comment: @itechy21: No, that's not valid. `[` is a *command*, not some part of the `if` syntax. The syntax for `if` is `if command-list; then then-command-list; else else-command-list; fi` and the test is whether the last command in `command-list` exits with a success (0) status code or not.

Comment: @itechy21: To check for failure, you  insert a `!`. I fixed the answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If either the ping **or** the kill succeed that second `sbalert` will trigger.

Shell `&&` and `||` are not ternary operators.

When the shell sees `a || b && c` it interprets that as `(a || b) && c` when you are expecting it to be `a || (b && c)`.

Either explicitly group your commands (e.g. `a || { b && c; }`) or use an explicit `if`.